# How to create a new dict item of keys which match what appears on multiple dicts or arrays? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, pattern-matching

```
List 1
['DEF', 'ABC', 'MNM']
List 2: 
['DEF', 'ABC', 'MNM']
List 3:
['ABC', 'MNM']
List 4:
['DEF', 'MNM']
List 5:
['ABC', 'MNM']
List 6:
{'DEF': [1.34], 'ABC': [0.44], 'MNM': [0.77]}
```

The goal for me is to find a subset of matching entries across these 6 lists (either dicts or arrays as shown above.)

- If I set a variable to match at least 6 times, I should get an output like final = {'MNM'} because 'MNM' appears on all of the above.
- If I set a variable to match at least 4 times, then I should get final = {'ABC', 'MNM'}
- If I set a variable to match at least 3 times, then I should get final = {'DEF', 'ABC', 'MNM'}

I don't know what's the **most efficient** way to perform this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Convert to sets, then you have set operations to help you

Answer (score 0):

It's a very rough code, you can make changes on it:

```
List1 = ['DEF', 'ABC', 'MNM']
List2 = ['DEF', 'ABC', 'MNM']
List3 = ['ABC', 'MNM']
List4 = ['DEF', 'MNM']
List5 = ['ABC', 'MNM']
List6 = {'DEF': [1.34], 'ABC': [0.44], 'MNM': [0.77]}

mapper = {1: List1, 2: List2, 3: List3, 4: List4, 5: List5, 6: List6}


def generate_elem_count():
    result_data = []
    for val in mapper.values():
        if type(val) == list:
            result_data += val
        elif type(val) == dict:
            for key in val:
                result_data.append(key)

    count_elem = {elem: result_data.count(elem) for elem in result_data}
    return count_elem


def get_from_min_match(var):
    temp = []
    count_elem = generate_elem_count()
    for item in count_elem:
        if var <= count_elem[item]:
            temp.append(item)
    return set(temp)


print(get_from_min_match(3))
print(get_from_min_match(4))
print(get_from_min_match(6))

# OUTPUT
# {'MNM', 'DEF', 'ABC'}
# {'MNM', 'DEF', 'ABC'}
# {'MNM'}
```

Also your second point is wrong: "If I set a variable to match at least 4 times, then I should get final = {'ABC', 'MNM'}".
It should rather be {'DEF', 'ABC', 'MNM'}